Take Screenshot using JavaFX
I am using the following code to take a window screenshot. The screenshot capture is from the wrong position if I take it on the second monitor with high resolution.
There should be an issue with coordinates conversion between JavaFX and Robots.
The screenshot works like this: it created a transparent window, on the screen size. The user can drag and drop an area, which will be used to take the screenshot.
import com.wisecoders.dbs.sys.Log;
import com.wisecoders.dbs.sys.fx.Alert$;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.geometry.BoundingBox;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

class SnapshotStage extends Stage {

    private final Screen screen;
    private final Canvas mainCanvas = new Canvas();
    private double clickX, clickY, dragX, dragY;
    private enum Status { waitForSelection, selectArea };
    private Status status = Status.waitForSelection;
    private File snapshotFile;

    private final URI storeURI;


    SnapshotStage(Screen screen, URI storeURI ){
        this.screen = screen;
        this.storeURI = storeURI;
        this.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        final StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent;");
        stackPane.getChildren().add( mainCanvas );

        Rectangle2D screenBounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, screenBounds.getWidth(), screenBounds.getHeight(), Color.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        setScene(scene);
        setX(screenBounds.getMinX());
        setY(screenBounds.getMinY());

        scene.addEventHandler( KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if ( e.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE ){
                SnapshotStage.this.close();
            }
        });
        mainCanvas.setWidth( screenBounds.getWidth() );
        mainCanvas.setHeight( screenBounds.getHeight() );
        mainCanvas.setOnMouseMoved( e -> {
            clickX = e.getX();
            clickY = e.getY();
            repaintCanvas();
        });
        mainCanvas.setOnMousePressed( e -> {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                clickX = e.getX();
                clickY = e.getY();
            }
        });
        mainCanvas.setOnMouseDragged( m -> {
            if ( m.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY ) {
                status = Status.selectArea;
                dragX = m.getX();
                dragY = m.getY();
                repaintCanvas();
            }
        });
        mainCanvas.setOnMouseReleased( m -> {
            if ( status == Status.selectArea ) {
                try {
                    if ( takeSnapshot()) {
                        final Media sound = new Media( String.valueOf( SnapshotStage.class.getResource("/icons/sounds/camera_shooter.mp3") ));
                        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
                        mediaPlayer.play();
                    }
                } catch ( Throwable ex ){
                    Log.error( ex );
                }
                SnapshotStage.this.close();
            }
        });
        Platform.runLater( this::repaintCanvas );
    }

    private boolean takeSnapshot() {
        double x = Math.min( clickX, dragX );
        double y = Math.min( clickY, dragY );
        double width = Math.abs(dragX - clickX - 1);
        double height = Math.abs(dragY - clickY - 1);
        if( width > 0 && height > 0 ) {
            final Bounds bounds = mainCanvas.localToScreen( new BoundingBox( x, y, width, height) );
            final WritableImage image = new javafx.scene.robot.Robot().getScreenCapture( null, bounds.getMinX() , bounds.getMinY() , bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight(), false);
            File file;
            int i = 0;
            while ((file = new File( storeURI.resolve("snapshot_" + i + ".png"))).exists()) {
                i++;
            }
            try {
                ImageIO.setUseCache(false);
                ImageIO.write( SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage( image, null ), "png", file);
                snapshotFile = file;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.error(ex);
                new Alert$(Alert.AlertType.ERROR).
                        withOwner(getScene()).
                        withTitle("Error").
                        withContextText(ex.toString()).
                        withException(ex).
                        show();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void repaintCanvas(){
        if ( mainCanvas.isVisible() && mainCanvas.getScene() != null ) {
            GraphicsContext gc = mainCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
            //gc.setFont(Font.font("null", FontWeight.BOLD, 14));

            gc.clearRect(0, 0, mainCanvas.getWidth(), mainCanvas.getHeight());
            gc.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
            gc.fillRect(0, 0, mainCanvas.getWidth(), mainCanvas.getHeight());

            if (status == Status.waitForSelection) {
                gc.setStroke( Color.web("#672824"));
                gc.setFill( Color.web("#672824"));
                gc.setLineWidth(1d);
                gc.strokeLine(clickX, 0, clickX, mainCanvas.getHeight());
                gc.strokeLine(0, clickY, mainCanvas.getWidth(), clickY);
                //gc.setStroke( Color.WHITE);
                gc.fillText("Drag to Select Screen Area", clickX + 10, clickY - 15 );
            } else {
                gc.clearRect(clickX, clickY, Math.abs(dragX - clickX), Math.abs(dragY - clickY));
                gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
                gc.setLineWidth(1d);
                gc.strokeRect(clickX - 1, clickY - 1, Math.abs(dragX - clickX) + 2, Math.abs(dragY - clickY) + 2);
            }
        }
    }

    File getSnapshotFile(){
        return snapshotFile;
    }


}


Wouldn't Node.snapShot() work?

Does this answer your question? Taking a screenshot of a scene or a portion of a scene in JavaFx 2.2

@DaveB As I understand it, Node.snapshot() will just snapshot the node, which is transparent. It won't get the (native) desktop which is showing behind it, which this code is intended to do.

Create a single Robot instance (instead of a new one for each screenshot) and try using Robot.getMousePosition() in the event handlers to record the mouse position. That should ensure you are using the same coordinate system for recording the mouse position and taking the snapshot.

Related: JavaFX effect on background

Somehow I am unable to reproduce the issue. Here is what I tried. I have two monitors with resolution (1920 x 1080 & 1920 x 1200). And I run the program to take screenshot on second monitor(higher resolution). The result image is exactly what I have taken. Can you be more specific about the issue. Like the steps, your screen specs.. etc

I implemented the solution with Robot.getMousePosition() and here is the latest code:
import com.wisecoders.dbs.sys.Log;
import com.wisecoders.dbs.sys.fx.Alert$;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.robot.Robot;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

class SnapshotStage extends Stage {
    private final Canvas mainCanvas = new Canvas();
    private final Robot robot = new javafx.scene.robot.Robot();
    private double stageClickX, stageClickY, stageDragX, stageDragY, robotClickX, robotClickY, robotDragX, robotDragY;
    private enum Status { waitForSelection, selectArea };
    private Status status = Status.waitForSelection;
    private File snapshotFile;

    private final URI storeURI;


    SnapshotStage(Screen screen, URI storeURI ){
        this.storeURI = storeURI;
        this.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        final StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent;");
        stackPane.getChildren().add( mainCanvas );

        Rectangle2D screenBounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, screenBounds.getWidth(), screenBounds.getHeight(), Color.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        setScene(scene);
        setX(screenBounds.getMinX());
        setY(screenBounds.getMinY());

        scene.addEventHandler( KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if ( e.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE ){
                SnapshotStage.this.close();
            }
        });
        mainCanvas.setWidth( screenBounds.getWidth() );
        mainCanvas.setHeight( screenBounds.getHeight() );
        mainCanvas.setOnMouseMoved( e -> {
            stageClickX = e.getX();
            stageClickY = e.getY();
            repaintCanvas();
        });
        mainCanvas.setOnMousePressed( e -> {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                stageClickX = e.getX();
                stageClickY = e.getY();
                robotClickX = robot.getMouseX();
                robotClickY = robot.getMouseY();
            }
        });
        mainCanvas.setOnMouseDragged( m -> {
            if ( m.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY ) {
                status = Status.selectArea;
                stageDragX = m.getX();
                stageDragY = m.getY();
                robotDragX = robot.getMouseX();
                robotDragY = robot.getMouseY();
                repaintCanvas();
            }
        });
        mainCanvas.setOnMouseReleased( m -> {
            if ( status == Status.selectArea ) {
                try {
                    if ( takeSnapshot()) {
                        final Media sound = new Media( String.valueOf( SnapshotStage.class.getResource("/icons/sounds/camera_shooter.mp3") ));
                        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
                        mediaPlayer.play();
                    }
                } catch ( Throwable ex ){
                    Log.error( ex );
                }
                SnapshotStage.this.close();
            }
        });
        Platform.runLater( this::repaintCanvas );
    }

    private boolean takeSnapshot() {
        double x = Math.min(robotClickX, robotDragX);
        double y = Math.min(robotClickY, robotDragY);
        double width = Math.abs(robotDragX - robotClickX - 1);
        double height = Math.abs(robotDragY - robotClickY - 1);
        if( width > 0 && height > 0 ) {
            final WritableImage image = robot.getScreenCapture( null, x, y, width, height, false);
            File file;
            int i = 0;
            while ((file = new File( storeURI.resolve("snapshot_" + i + ".png"))).exists()) {
                i++;
            }
            try {
                ImageIO.setUseCache(false);
                ImageIO.write( SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage( image, null ), "png", file);
                snapshotFile = file;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.error(ex);
                new Alert$(Alert.AlertType.ERROR).
                        withOwner(getScene()).
                        withTitle("Error").
                        withContextText(ex.toString()).
                        withException(ex).
                        show();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void  repaintCanvas(){
        if ( mainCanvas.isVisible() && mainCanvas.getScene() != null ) {
            GraphicsContext gc = mainCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
            //gc.setFont(Font.font("null", FontWeight.BOLD, 14));

            gc.clearRect(0, 0, mainCanvas.getWidth(), mainCanvas.getHeight());
            gc.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
            gc.fillRect(0, 0, mainCanvas.getWidth(), mainCanvas.getHeight());

            if (status == Status.waitForSelection) {
                gc.setStroke( Color.web("#672824"));
                gc.setFill( Color.web("#672824"));
                gc.setLineWidth(1d);
                gc.strokeLine(stageClickX, 0, stageClickX, mainCanvas.getHeight());
                gc.strokeLine(0, stageClickY, mainCanvas.getWidth(), stageClickY);
                //gc.setStroke( Color.WHITE);
                gc.fillText("Drag to Select Screen Area", stageClickX + 10, stageClickY - 15 );
            } else {
                gc.clearRect(stageClickX, stageClickY, Math.abs(stageDragX - stageClickX), Math.abs(stageDragY - stageClickY));
                gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
                gc.setLineWidth(1d);
                gc.strokeRect(stageClickX - 1, stageClickY - 1, Math.abs(stageDragX - stageClickX) + 2, Math.abs(stageDragY - stageClickY) + 2);
            }
        }
    }

    File getSnapshotFile(){
        return snapshotFile;
    }


}



